# Кто сталкивался Bootstrap Sidebar Nav

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

На сайте [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview) есть боковое меню, которое при скроле автоматически добавляет пунктам класс `.active`. Но на самом сайте я не нашел описания, как его реализовать, может кто сталкивался с таким меню, ткните пальцем плиз.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382551/making-a-menu-class-active-when-scrolled-past

Comment: там только пункты меню, а с подпунктами? И не используются библиотеки bootstrap

Comment: Вот нашел пример, правда придется над последним блоком поработать, немного не корректно работает https://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/S2SMK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делает плагин ScrollSpy. Вот он на сайте бутстрапа http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy